# How do you use file_get_contents() on PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Usually, you could just enter the URL from a website to get the HTML code. However, on PhpStorm, when I try to do:

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost:63342/Prj1_Submission1/index.php?_ijt=i77g98br35guk27egnuaaj3va6")
```

where the URL is generated by PhpStorm for my index.php it gives me this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:63342/Prj1_Submission1/index.php?_ijt=i77g98br35guk27egnuaaj3va6): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in C:\Users\prajw\PhpstormProjects\Prj1_Submission1\search.php on line 18
```

Comment: PHPStorm is just an IDE and should be irrelevant to the application. Something may be wrong/incompatible with your web server. If you hit the URL in your browser, do you get the expected result? Please give us more detailed information like your web server, PHP version etc.

Comment: *"`http://localhost:63342/Prj1_Submission1/i...`"* This kind of URL is used by the PhpStorm's own built-in **simple** web server. Can you use proper Apache/nginx/IIS/etc instead? If you can -- just create a Deployment entry (In-Place type may work fine), specify URL there and mark as Default for this project. Now IDE will generate URLs based on that info when you use "Open in Browser" or alike actions in IDE.